# Resolve NPM package dependency from npmjs.com deployed in Artifactory

Tags: react-native, npm, artifactory

We are developing a internal react native library and we use our internal artifactory to publish it. I was successfully able to publish my npm package to our internal artifactory. However I can't resolve it.

My package has some dependencies (`@react-native-community/netinfo, @types/react-native, inversify, uuid` for example). When I try to resolve the dependency, the `npm install` command tries to resolves the dependencies from our internal artifactory, but my dependencies are not in my internal artifactory (they are in the npmjs.com). So the npm install fails.

This is the command I use to install my package

```
npm install my-awesome-react-native-sdk --registry https://artifactory.mycompany.tools/artifactory/api/npm/repo-folder-name/
```

Here is the full output

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: demo@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-community/netinfo@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/netinfo@"^9.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-native-community/netinfo@"^9.3.0" from my-awesome-react-native-sdk@0.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/my-awesome-react-native-sdk
npm ERR!   my-awesome-react-native-sdk@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Virtual Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories) in order to resolve dependencies from the npm registry, if they don't exist in your local repository.

To do so, first create a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RemoteRepositories) (pointed at https://registry.npmjs.org for example).
Then create a virutal repository, and add your local and remote repositories to it. The dependency resolution will fallback from your local repository to the remote one if the dependency cannot be found.